# How do I authenticate requests to AWS API Gateway RestAPI using Azure AD application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, aws-api-gateway

For example, suppose I created

- Users in Azure AD
- Application in Azure for a restful API
- API Management Service which delegated to this application when validating a token in requests (scope)

Then, I switched to AWS API Gateway RestAPI as my API front end gateway, but still have my users defined in AzureAD.
How can I add authentication to the AWS RestAPI such that requests with tokens are validated against the users and scopes defined in Azure AD application?

Said another way, If I was to go with Azure API Management service, I could create an application in azure, add users to that application, add roles to users within that application, and once I setup the API within the api management service instance, point to this application when validation tokens.

Is it possible to use AWS RestAPI and authenticate requests against an Azure AD app with the mix of technologies I described above?

Perhaps another way of asking this would be to ask:
How do I setup authentication with AWS RestAPI with https://auth0.com/?

The same area of the policy to update may be the same. Any insight is appreciated.

The comparable substitute in Azure is here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests

I see some docs for HTTP APIs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html But I am specifically looking for this type of feature in RestAPI

Comment: did you solve this? the authorizer are built in for the http api but lacking for rest api

Comment: exactly, i think it was lambda authorizer as only option, but limited based on type of proxy like you said.